# Using Ajax with Django to call backend and display result

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am taking user input and sending it to Django backend for some text processing. After performing backend operation I want to display results.

I tried but as I am new with ajax,I am not sure where I am making mistake. Can anyone please give me correct way of using ajax for this operation? I appreciate if you can give link to any good reference document.

Current issue - When I click on submut button it removes input text area.

[image]
[image]

My html report.html -

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>StopWordsRemoval</h1>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(form).on('submit', function(event){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'stopwordsremoval/(?P<document1>.+)'
            type: 'POST',
            data: this.serialize(),
        }); 
    });
});
</script>

<div>
<form  method = "post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form}}

    <button type="submit">stopwordsremoval</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div >
        <ul>
            <li>{{ naturallanguageprocessing }}</li> 
        </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'stopwordsremoval' %}" </a>
<style>
    div {
        width: 1000px;
        border: 5px solid green;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
</div>
  </div>

  {% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url    
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'stopwordsremoval/$', views.stopwordsremoval.as_view(), name='stopwordsremoval'),
    url(r'stopwordsremoval/(?P<document1>.+)/$',
        views.ReportDetails.as_view(), name='report_details'),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    #pdb.set_trace()
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5, 'cols': 100}))
```

Comment: If you use Ajax you shouldn't use a submit button. You should just use an event listener that listens to a button click and runs a function that contains the Ajax call.

Comment: Your Ajax isn't running at all, because the form is being submitted normally.

Comment: thanks.I am new to ajax can anyone help how to call form in ajax

Comment: You should write your form view and urls first, to make sure it works properly and then add the ajax support; as a rule of thumb.

Comment: yes everything working fine in backend only ajax to add at frontend

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(button).on('click', function(event){
        var form = $(form).serialize()
        $.ajax({
            url: 'stopwordsremoval/(?P<document1>.+)' // this will not work
            type: 'POST',
            data: form,
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can u help me how to write url above is urls.py